# Mongo aggregate remove group if condition in sub array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

At a certain point of my pipeline, I have a structure like this :

```
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        elems1: [{sub : {date: xxx}}, {sub: {date: yyy}}],
        elems2: [{sub: {date: zzz}}, {sub: {date: qqq}}]
    },
    ...
]
```

Which comes from a grouping :

```
{$group: {
    _id: '$user.id',
    elems1: {
        $push: {sub: '$other'}
        },
    elems2: {
        $push: {sub: '$other'}
        }
    }
}}
```

Now I want to delete the groups that have an element in `elems1` OR `elems2` with `sub.date` less than a certain date, how could I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do your `$group`, you can also track the "minElemDate" and then `$match` by that in the next pipeline stage.

```
$group: {
  _id: "$user.id",
  elem1s: ...,
  elem2s: ...
  minElemDate: {
    $min: {
      $cond: [
        { $or: [condition1, condition2] },
       "$user.date",
        null
      ]
    }
  }
},
{ $match: {$gte: ["$minElemDate", minDate]} }
```

Comment: I like this idea, can you please elaborate on what to put in `condition1` and `condition2` ? That's the part where I'm confused

Comment: `{$eq: ['$user.name', 'L']}` and `{$eq: ['$user.name', 'L']}` -- it seems like those are the elements that you care about

Comment: I will remove this part, maybe it is making it confusing. I care only about the date... I will update my question

Comment: tldr of my answer -- when you do the group, also track the min date. don't try and filter it out afterwards because it'll be harder

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what to put in the `$min` block, since I want the min of the object date inside the array

Comment: So put "$other.date" -- you're trying to get the minimum for that field